# JavaScript Factory pattern without if-else block

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I was wondering if there is a better way to implement the createEmployee() that uses a dictionary or some other way to quickly lookup the type being requested rather than the if-else block.

```
function Clerk( options ) {
            this.hourRate = options.hourRate || 20;
            this.firstName = options.firstName || "no first name";
            this.lastName = options.lastName || "no last name";
            this.id = options.id || "-9999999999";
        }

        function Manager( options) {
            this.hourRate = options.hourRate || 200;
            this.firstName = options.firstName || "no first name";
            this.lastName = options.lastName || "no last name";
            this.id = options.id || "-9999999999";
            this.yearBonus = options.yearBonus || "200000";
        }

        function Teacher( options) {
            this.hourRate = options.hourRate || 100;
            this.firstName = options.firstName || "no first name";
            this.lastName = options.lastName || "no last name";
            this.id = options.id || "-9999999999";
            this.subject = options.subject || "history";
        }

        var EmployeesFactory = function() {};

        EmployeesFactory.prototype.createEmployee = function (options) {
            if(options.employeeType == "Clerk")
                employeeConstructor = Clerk;
            else if(options.employeeType == "Manager")
                employeeConstructor = Manager;
            else if(options.employeeType == "Teacher")
                employeeConstructor = Teacher;
            return new employeeConstructor(options);
        }

        var factory = new EmployeesFactory();
        var person = factory.createEmployee( {
            employeeType: "Manager",
            firstName: "Haim",
            lastName: "Michael",
            id: 234234234 } );

        document.write(person instanceof Manager);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var constructors;

constructors = {
    "Clerk" : function (options) {
        // your constructor code here for clerks
    },
    "Manager" : function (options) {
        // your constructor code here for managers
    },
    "Teacher" : function (options) {
        // your constructor code here for teachers
    }
};

EmployeesFactory.prototype.createEmployee = function (options) {
    return constructors[options.employeeType](options);
};
```

I recommend keeping the `constructors` object well hidden inside `EmployeesFactory`.
This way you also get rid of the undesired function names (`Clerk`, `Manager` and `Teacher`).

Also, you should create the `constructors` object only once and reuse it in the create. Don't instantiate it in the create. You can do this in the following way:

```
var EmployeesFactory = function () {
    var constructors;

    constructors = {
        "Clerk" : function (options) {
            // your constructor code here for clerks
        },
        "Manager" : function (options) {
            // your constructor code here for managers
        },
        "Teacher" : function (options) {
            // your constructor code here for teachers
        }
    };

    return {
        "create" : function (options) {
            return constructors[options.employeeType](options);
        }
    };
};
```

You get the factory this way:

```
factory = EmployeesFactory();
```

And can create stuff this way:

```
factory.create(options);
```

All will be cozy and hidden inside the outer enveloping closure with no guts hanging outside.

The intention of the *Factory Pattern* is to hide the complexity and details of object construction, so keeping the methods *around* for consumption is missing out on an aspect (I admit, minor/minimal) of the pattern. By using closures you'll get the benefits of the hiding, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you said, use a dictionary:

```
function createEmployee(options) {
    return new {
        "Clerk": Clerk,
        "Manager": Manager,
        "Teacher": Teacher
    }[options.employeeType](options);
}
```

Maybe make the object literal a static variable `constructors`, and re-introduce the intermediate `employeeConstructor` variable for more verbosity and less confusing syntax :-)

---

Btw, there's lots of code duplication in your constructors. You could make that more DRY:

```
function Employee(options, defaultRate) {
    this.hourRate = options.hourRate || defaultRate;
    this.firstName = options.firstName || "no first name";
    this.lastName = options.lastName || "no last name";
    this.id = options.id || "-9999999999";
}

function Clerk(options) {
    Employee.call(this, options, 20);
}
function Manager(options) {
    Employee.call(this, options, 200);
    this.yearBonus = options.yearBonus || "200000";
}
function Teacher(options) {
    Employee.call(this, options, 100);
    this.subject = options.subject || "history";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the below will be cleaner code.

```
// Create this one time
var constructors = {};

constructors["Manager"] = Manager
constructors["Teacher"] = Teacher
...

// Each object
return new constructors[options.employeeType](options);
```